# Electric Fan not Working

Tags: repair, appliances, electric-motor, diy-vs-pro

I have a [water distiller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaETy.jpg) which the electric fan suddenly just stopped working (thankfully I was near by to shutdown everything, otherwise ...). Prior to the failure everything was working fine, there was no warnings. And just after the failure there was a burning smell.

I've removed the [electric motor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTfIC.jpg) to do some testing:

- It is not jammed or stuck since I can spin it fine with my fingers.
- There is no visual damage in it.
- It doesn't work even if connected directly into the power outlet.

There is a [teardown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J-jjbH688UU) of a similar model that might be useful for the discussion.

**Question**

I've tried to find some DIY repair for this kind of electric motor but could not find.
Is it possible to fix it? How?

Comment: Does this fan have a capacitor? Could be a bulging failed one if so.

Comment: @JeffCates I'm not sure. But I posted an image of the [electric motor](https://imgur.com/zsrGthU). Does it has a capacitor?

Comment: Nope. That little guy...strictly magnetic pulse. I would bet that it ran to long and fried the winding.

Comment: Your video link only shows the machine teardown. Like I commented, most likely the windinghas shorted from getting to hot. Similar type motor in refrigerators, bathroom exhaust fans, range hoods, etc. Hence the burning smell. Time for a new motor unless you want to rewind that, as it would probably cost more to get fixed than replace.

Comment: it sounds to me like the problem is not the motor, but something "upstream" of it. A motor should take quite a while between not spinning and smelling burnt, and you say you were right there to stop it. Electrical components smell bad almost the same instant a problem develops.

Comment: @JeffCates _> "I would bet that it ran to long and fried the winding."_ It has +5yo. But I'm using it strictly according the manual.

Comment: @JeffCates _> "Your video link only shows the machine teardown."_ I've also made a [simple video](https://streamable.com/67x25) of it.

Comment: @JeffCates _> "most likely the windinghas shorted from getting to hot."_ I would expect that such kind of electric motor should last much longer. I'm wondering why would it get so hot? As far as I could see, it was spinning without much friction ...

Comment: @JeffCates _> "it would probably cost more to get fixed than replace."_ I've already tried, unfortunately could not find spare parts.

Comment: @dandavis _> "it sounds to me like the problem is not the motor, but something "upstream" of it."_ I've already removed the electric motor from the case and plugged it directly into the power outlet, unfortunately it did not worked. Moreover, there is no continuity between the two wires (red/green) that goes into the power outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a shaded pole motor there is no fixing them if they spin easily, usually the bearings dry out and the motor won't spin a few drops of light oil in each end may fix it but if not, it's time for a new one. These motors rarely burn up it is usually the bearings being dry that causes them to fail. So try and and add oil to the bearings by putting a few drops on the shaft and spinning to help the oil work into it. Do this on both sides and the motor may come back to life.

Comment: _> "there is no fixing them if they spin easily"_ The motor is spinning easily. While it was working, there were no signs of reduced speed.

Comment: _> "These motors rarely burn up"_ Considering that there is no continuity between the wires that go into the power outlet, my best guess at the time is that the coil is burnt. What do you think?

Comment: I did not see that there was no continuity across the coil, with that info the motor is toast. That is rare for a shaded pole motor usually the bearings freeze up and the motor can be brought back to life with a few drops of oil. The coil could be rewound but by the time you purchase the wire the cost of a new motor would only be a few $ more. If you are really into repairing this you would need to measure the length of wire on the coil and the diameter and rewind I have done this in the past for a specialty motor that cost almost 1K. Your motor can probably be found from 20-50$

Comment: There are usually numbers on the motor if you could provide those we may be able to help you source one.

Comment: _> "I did not see that there was no continuity across the coil"_ After posting the issue, someone suggested a continuity test. There is no continuity across the wires coming out of the coil. Later I will update the original post.

Comment: _> "you would need to measure the length of wire on the coil and the diameter"_ Would just using the same wire with the same length be enough? Is it really necessary to know the diameter of the coil?

Comment: _> "If you are really into repairing"_ No, I'm not. Unfortunately, I dont have much options. I've already tried to buy a new one but could not find.

Comment: _> "There are usually numbers on the motor"_ Chinese motor: no brand, no specs, no serial number, nothing. The best I have are the pictures I've submitted over this page.

Comment: Hand wiring is a very tough job, but it can be done, is it worth it? Probably not on this unit because of the time required. 100' of this type of wire may take days winding by hand in place , I would try to find a similar motor with the size it could be the same size as a small refrigerator as long as the same shaft size and mounting holes match it would work, if turning the wrong direction (ccw / cw ) turn the stator 180. And it will go the correct direction on a shaded pole motor, I have found after market motors for 20$ when the OEM motor was 3 to 10x the cost and higher.