# Electric Motor: Spark and Repair Issues

Tags: repair, appliances, electric-motor, diy-vs-pro

I'm trying to repair a shaded pole induction motor from a home appliance. However, each time I connect the motor to the power outlet there is a spark in the same place (I've already tried 2x):

- [video: electric motor spark](https://streamable.com/k0zct)

Any idea?

---

## Additional Notes

**Home Appliance**
More information about the problem with such home appliance:

- [Electric Fan not Working](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/159651/electric-fan-not-working)
- [Water Distiller: Reassembly Issues](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160145/water-distiller-reassembly-issues)

**Electric Motor**

It seems this electric motor is Chinese, unfortunately there is no tag in it. My best guest is the following description:

- 120 VAC, 60Hz, 20W

**Soldering**

To solder the wire from the coil, I've done the following steps:

1. Remove the coating of the wire by applying some solder ([How to solder enameled copper wire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjjryf2aqaY))
2. Overlapping the wires ([Soldering Thin Wires](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fopGW8T3Avs))

After that I did a continuity test to confirm the circuit was fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because continuity, alone, is an indicator of nothing.

Actually, you've got way too much continuity!  But you are not testing for that.   You should test the resistance of the coil, better, measure its inductance.  Not happy stuff.

This is the crux of your problem.  You have a shorted coil.  It's very obvious, from the big arc flash coming from the receptacle, that the coil is much lower impedance than it should be.   That kind of arc flash is TROUBLE and you should not provoke it.

The arc flash occurring at  the coil itself is telling you what's gone wrong.  Some of the varnish insulation has failed and coils are shorting.  You need to rewind this motor.